# Cannot set block-no-empty to false in stylelint

Tags: stylelint

Given the following in `package.json`:

`"stylelint": {
    "extends": "stylelint-config-standard",
    "rules": {
      "string-quotes": "single",
      "block-no-empty": false,
      "indentation": 2
    }
  }`

I'm having trouble figuring out how to override `block-no-empty`. If I set it to `false`, I get the error:

`Invalid Option: Unexpected option value "false" for rule "block-no-empty"`

Am I missing some kind of override syntax?

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `null` to turn a rule off e.g. `"block-no-empty": null`.

More details can be found in the [configuration guide](http://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration/#the-configuration-object).

There is also [an example](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard#extending-the-config) in the `stylelint-config-standard` README showing how to extend the config and turn off a rule.